# Apt-get commands failing with dependency issues after upgrading from 14 to 16

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

The output from an apt-get upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-clutter : Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not     installable
 libnux-4.0-0 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installable
 orage : Depends: libical1 (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
 python : Depends: python-minimal (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but 2.7.11-1 is installed
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.11-1) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is installed
              Depends: libpython-dev (= 2.7.11-1) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: gstreamer1.0-clutter in 16.04 deps on libcogl20, seems your upgrade had issues. What does `apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0-clutter` return?

Comment: @doug `> apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0-clutter
gstreamer1.0-clutter:
  Installed: 2.0.8-1build1
  Candidate: 2.0.18-1
  Version table:
     2.0.18-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 2.0.8-1build1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Try this - `sudo apt update`  followed by `sudo apt -s dist-upgrade` this is just a simulation, do the packages mentioned in your post get upgraded?

Comment: @doug Same error as above after running both commands

Comment: Seems like a real mess. orage & python-dev you could just remove but the other 3.. Sometimes one can go retrieve the newer packages & install with dpkg  or apt but this may be 'deeper' What happens if you try to install   libcogl20, do as a simulation, `sudo apt -s install  libcogl20`

Comment: @doug that gives me the same error as before. I managed to update everything but python-minimal, python, and python-dev by downloading the packages manually and installing with dpkg. The output of any apt command now is `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python : Depends: python-minimal (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but 2.7.11-1 is installed
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.11-1) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is installed` Any ideas?

Comment: Well for the moment you can just remove python-dev, re-install later if desired. What happens with python & dpkg?  (python-minimal is already installed at correct version

Answer (score 0):

Some packages got obsoleted between 14.04 and 16.04, it's a very common occurence when upgrading distros. Here's what you do:

-see if your problem packages are available for 16.04. If they are, you may wish to `sudo apt-get purge` those packages and then re-install them. Your packages may have different dependencies under 16.04, but since they've been installed under 14.04, they have THAT list of delendencies.

-make sure your `sources.list` only contain valid entries for 16.04

-you may wish to reinstall 16.04 cleanly from scratch. "Dirty upgrades" like this don't always work 100% out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I've just upgraded from 14.04 Trusty to 16.04 Xenial.  I hit this problem where libcogl20 could not be installed because it broke libcogl15 and there were a number of dependencies on libcogl15, particularly the ubuntu-desktop package.  I obviously did not want to remove ubuntu-desktop and I could find no help here or on IRC.  This is what I did to resolve this.

I booted into recovery mode.  This has an option marked 'dpkg' that says it will fix broken packages.  I chose that and libcogl15 was going to be removed with a couple of other packages, I can't remember the names, but they did not include ubuntu-desktop so I decided this would fix my problem and it did.

There were a couple of things I needed to do before running the dpkg recover option.  First I needed to connect and ethernet cable and start networking (another option on the recovery menu).  Then I need to enter root terminal (another option).  There I found that resolv.conf was not populated so I had to create that with the nameserver.  I also found to route was wrong, so I need to add the correct default route.

After that I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> to return to the menu and chose the dpkg option.  This magically sorted out my problem and I am now working successfully.

hth